# Tensorflow sparse tensor with vector value to dense tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some sparse indices:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 0]]
```

The corresponding value of each index is:

```
[[0.1 0.2 0.3]
 [0.4 0.5 0.6]
 [0.7 0.8 0.9]
 [1.0 1.1 1.2]
 [1.3 1.4 1.5]
 [1.6 1.7 1.8]]
```

How to convert the 6x3 value tensor to 3x3x3 dense tensor in tensorflow? The value for indices not specified in indices is zero vector [0. 0. 0.]. The dense tensor is just like this:

```
[[[0.1 0.2 0.3]
  [0.4 0.5 0.6]
  [0.0 0.0 0.0]]

 [[0.7 0.8 0.9]
  [1.0 1.1 1.2]
  [1.3 1.4 1.5]]

 [[1.6 1.7 1.8]
  [0.0 0.0 0.0]
  [0.0 0.0 0.0]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    indices = tf.constant(
        [[0, 0],
         [0, 1],
         [1, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [1, 2],
         [2, 0]])
    values = tf.constant(
        [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
         [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
         [0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
         [1.0, 1.1, 1.2],
         [1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
         [1.6, 1.7, 1.8]])
    out = tf.scatter_nd(indices, values, [3, 3, 3])
    print(sess.run(out))
```

Output:

```
[[[0.1 0.2 0.3]
  [0.4 0.5 0.6]
  [0.  0.  0. ]]

 [[0.7 0.8 0.9]
  [1.  1.1 1.2]
  [1.3 1.4 1.5]]

 [[1.6 1.7 1.8]
  [0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0. ]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no definite way to do it in Tensorflow using any `reshape` kind of function. I could only think about an iterative solution by creating a list and converting it back to a Tensor. This is perhaps not the most efficient solution, but this might work for your code.

```
# list of indices 
idx=[[0,0],[0,1], [1,0],[1,1], [1,2], [2,0]]

# Original Tensor to reshape
dense_tensor=tf.Variable([[0.1, 0.2 ,0.3],[0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9], [1.0,1.1,1.2],[1.3,1.4,1.5], [1.6,1.7,1.8]])

# creating a temporary list to later convert to Tensor
c=np.zeros([3,3,3]).tolist()

for i in range(3):
    count=0
    for j in range(3):
        if([i,j] in idx):
            c[i][j]=dense_tensor[count]
            count=count+1
        else:
            c[i][j]=tf.Variable([0,0,0], dtype=tf.float32)

# Convert obtained list to Tensor
converted_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(c, dtype=tf.float32)
```

You can define the ranges depending upon the size of Tensor you want. For your case, I have chosen 3 as you wanted a 3x3x3 Tensor. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much. But I need to implement it by tensorflow op, because it's part of a graph.

Comment: I think it will not cause you any problems as I am directly assigning values from the input tensor to the new Tensor. Even the Tensors of 0s which are added will comply with the graph operations. If you feel like the list to Tensor conversion will cause a problem, then it won't as the Tensors are still connected and I have personally implemented this without a problem. So give it a shot and let me know if it causes you any problems!